# Sending data between Lua and Python

Tags: python, lua

I'm handling an emulator with built in Lua functions.

Most of my code is python but I need to access some of the variables, Lua is getting from the emulator, in python. I need the Lua to wait for python to answer back before continuing the script.

The python is constantly running as is the Lua code.

All I can think of is:

a) putting up a server on Python and connecting to it with Lua.

b) writing to files with Lua and reading it with Python, while constantly scanning the files with Lua checking if Python has read them. I find this idea really slow.

Comment: Option a sounds about right. REST APIs are pretty useful for getting around issues like these.

Comment: You can try e.g. ZeroMQ.

Comment: @PrateekDewan And by REST what you actually mean is HTTP?

Comment: I actually made a lua tcp client and python tcp server. All is working now. :)